# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election - Nominations begin September 7th

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Writing Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **September 7th** to bring on more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on September 7th, users can [nominate themselves](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/2). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On September 14th, if there are enough candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate/s. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, we'll announce the results on meta on September 22nd.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

---

### A few notes.

This post is serving a couple purposes - different than it usually does. This site has changed a lot in the last year so this election means something different than it might have a year ago. Last year, after particularly strong nudges from the people in this community, I, and the other CMs were excited to have it leave Beta and enter "full site" status. It was something y'all celebrated and was an opportunity for future growth.

All of that changed in September when longstanding moderator Monica Cellio was removed from her position here and on several other sites. I can't discuss this; either the past events or the future but what I can say is that the impact on this site has been huge. Many of your most avid contributors and curators left, some even deleting their accounts. This loss of community has gravely impacted the site and changed its trajectory.

For the last few months I've been waiting for the right time to take this next step. Perhaps I've waited longer than I should have and I'd planned to get this rolling sooner but I was concerned about dredging up bad memories and I wanted to see whether the site pulled together or continued to degrade. I think that - hope that - moving forward and electing a moderator team will help this site work towards building up excellence again.

I can't give you back what you lost and I can't even say that this will get you back to where you were - I don't think it will - but I do think that this is an opportunity for y'all to decide what's next and how you can shape yourselves for this next era.

Because of everything above, this is a beta-style election. Y'all aren't in beta but it seemed unfair to run this election like a full site election, which would require Cyn - who's been keeping flags handled and tending the site - to run if she chose to continue. I don't want to force her into that but I do want to get her some help if she chooses to stay. Either way, much appreciation is due to Cyn. I understand this has been a rocky road and I'm sorry for that.

### My ask

1. If you're interested in nominating, leave a comment or answer below. This will help me get an idea of whether there's much interest and what I should expect next week. This is completely optional and non-binding - you neither need to say anything, nor are you expected to nominate if you say you will. The standard rules apply - you have to have >300 reputation to nominate.
2. Let me know if you have thoughts or questions. This can be about the election, the site health, the future of Writing. If I can't answer for some reason, I'll let you know.

Thanks to those of you who have continued to be active here and to the people who built this site up over the years. This site has been an incredible resource for so many people I'd love to see that continue.

Comment: Thank you for this. While I fear the answer will be that you can't comment exactly what will happen I want to ask: what would happen to the site if nobody nominated themselves? Furthermore I would like to ask: how is the [automation of the election process](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2130/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta/2133#comment5571_2133) coming along? And a little thing: why is "Arts & Crafts" linked with the "nominate themselves" link instead of Writing.SE?

Comment: The A&C link was a copy-paste issue. Apologies for that. As for getting no nominations... it's pretty much the one thing that keeps sites around. If there's insufficient community to field a team of moderators, we give it a couple chances but then the inevitable outcome is shutting the site down. We need community moderators for sites and we can't leave sites unmoderated. This is explained in more detail [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614). While we no longer use 10 QPD as a trigger for graduation, the second bullet point about moderation stands - even on graduated sites.

Comment: The site is valuable. My participation has been minimal. I understand the process of moderation, and how effective moderation builds community, and indirectly builds value for Stack Exchange. I am low-rep on Writing SE.  I am still learning the standards of this community. I have made the mistake in some sites when putting forward a question of not sensitizing myself adequately to the standards of that site.  Within SE, every site is different.  Good behavior on one site is reprehensible on another.  SE Writing is a good, friendly site, which I value.

Comment: I haven't been terribly active, but I threw my hat in the ring. I can help out a bit if it keeps this community going.

Answer (score 6):

I've been waiting for an election to happen here, and I'll gladly put myself forward as a candidate. Even if I don't win, we're definitely overdue some new mods to help Cyn out.

In terms of the site's health, I do feel like activity here has increased again over the last few months, and we've built up a brand-new community to replace the old one. Whether that community is as active as the old one, I can't say, but Writing.SE definitely isn't the ghost town I feared it would become after the loss of so many high-rep users. I'm pleased with the state that the site is currently in - especially since it could have been so much worse.

Comment: I would like to voice my support for you, you're an excellent moderator candidate and I always see you making helpful edits and contributions. Would love if you were a moderator here.

Comment: I was going to nominate you.  I'm barely here anymore I realize, I just pop on to keep the site moderated.  But please know that I've noticed all the work you do here.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not that active lately, if people want me to and it prevents the site closing, I'm prepared to be a moderator.